# Create instances or models for buying and selling a product in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am debating on how to structure a Rails application that involves buying and selling books. What I want to accomplish is for every user who buys a book, there will be a page with a list of users who bought books. In addition, for every user who sells a book, there will be a page with a list of users who are selling books.

Should I create a book model and create instances every time a user buys/sells a book or should I create a buy model and sell model that refer back to the book model?

I've read about modules and mixins and feel that this might be a good alternative. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You want User, Book, Order and OrderLine or equivalent models.

Book stored the listing on your site, the current price and other information. Order would be a user's cart and/or invoice for each purchase he does, this has many order lines. Those point to the book bought, but store the price at the time of the transaction. It's important that you keep this price, because the book price can change after.

A more complicated setup has different models for orders and invoices, but that's up to you.

Comment: You say "It's important that you keep this price, because the book price can change after." That depends upon requirements. It's entirely possible that the system doesn't even care about price in terms of exchanges of books. For example LibraryThing or GoodReads. the current price is interesting to present as data to the user but otherwise unimportant.

Comment: @jaydel Well, usually when you the site being build "involves buying and selling books" price matters. When it does, my comment applies; when it doesn't, I wouldn't call it buying and selling.

Comment: I always try to just answer the questions as they are asked, not with any assumptions of my own. no big deal though

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a User and a Book model, and build a user has many books relationship. For example:

```
class User
  has_many :books
end

class Book
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then you can run a migration for the book model to create a two columns
is_sold or is_bought, and set a boolean on each whenever a book is sold or bought.

Whenever you need create a list of books bought by a certain user, you can select all the books based on the conditions that the book belongs to the user and is_sold/is_bought is true.

Comment: Does this solution end up with multiple records for the same book? For example there will be a book linking 'is_sold' to the seller and 'is_bought' to the purchaser? And if someone sells a book they just bought you'd end up with two more book records? I hadn't considered this approach. It does seem to remove the idea of a book being a unique object in the data model. not sure how the OPs situation mixes with that.

Comment: in that case, you will want to use a many-to-many relationship between user and book, which involves creating a new schema. And I would put the is_sold/is_bought in the new table.

Comment: Don't call models Model, `User` and `Book` are enough.

Comment: @davidhu2000 Thank you for your response. Prior to asking, I had a similar idea on how to approach the problem.

Comment: @jaydel Eventually, I would like a master reference where anyone can go and see which book they would want regardless if someone buys/sells it. In that case, the books would be unique objects. However, even if two users have the same book, wouldn't those two physical books be different objects? I am not sure if I fully understand OO programming just yet.

Comment: You can represent the books at an instance of a book (meaning there might be 40,000 copies of The Hobbit) or you might represent them at the conceptual level (there is only one The Hobbit but the many copies are represented as rows relating the single book to a single user. If you get to the point where you want to know how many copies are out there, you might adjust this slightly, of course. The data will be there, but the representation might not be clear enough for your purposes

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in historical auditing of the data--in capturing metadata about the sales/purchase transaction itself, then I'd go with a users table, a book table, and a book_transaction table. You can use STI to differentiate the two types of book_transactions (this opens you up for more options down the road, for example a book_return_type, etc).

In the STI case mixins and scopes definitely will improve the implementation.

If you don't care for STI you can just have a single model, but in this particular case it might be powerful to have a pair of models that leverage this table.

You're asking good questions. The answers will be inextricably tied to what you need to do with the data, of course, and I have limited insight into that.

Comment: I didn't even think about a book_transaction table. That will definitely help keeping tabs on what is going on in a single table. Excuse my lack of knowledge, but STI? Did a quick search and found Single Table Inheritance. I am positive you didn't mean Sexually Transmitted Infection.

Comment: Just to clarify, would the book_transactions table be the table to inherit from the book table?

Comment: yes, sorry, Single Table Inheritance. Basically you have a 'type' column in the table and can have different model implementations that rely on that type for self identification. In my little answer you'd have a table for books, one for users and then a separate table + model that relates books to users.